# Show other field than title for some page types in TYPO3 backend page tree

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

We have an extension in TYPO3 8.7, which we're updating to TYPO3 10.4. One thing the extension does is alter the page tree in the backend so for some page types a different field than title is shown. For TYPO3 8 we're using a hook for that: `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/tree/pagetree/class.t3lib_tree_pagetree_dataprovider.php']['postProcessCollections']` where we could loop through the page tree nodes, check the doktype and replace the text.

The page tree has been completely rewritten in TYPO3 9, so this hook doesn't exist anymore. I've looked in the new `TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\Page\TreeController` class, but don't see any Signal Slot or PSR-14 event in that class we can use.

Is there a way to manipulate the page tree in this way in TYPO3 10?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the *Navigation Title* field (`nav_title`) provided by TYPO3 out of the box, you can use the Page TSConfig option [`showNavTitle`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/10.4/en-us/UserTsconfig/Options.html#pagetree-shownavtitle) to prefer that in the page tree if set for a page:

```
pageTree {
  showNavTitle = 1
}
```

[If `nav_title` is empty](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/10.4/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/Page/TreeController.php#L329), the regular `title` is shown instead.

Comment: I thought about that, but was hoping there was a better solution. I might just end up xclassing the `TreeController`